# function component re-render is not executed in spite of set*** called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My script is like this below,

After api fetch the items, I want to rerender component and make `EnhancedTable` appered.

However this script, api fetch success, but EnhancedTable is not appeared.

response.data returns correct data but, re-render is not executed.

Where am I wrong?

```
const MetaPanel = (props) =>{
    const [drawingItems,setDrawingItems] = React.useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("File List");
        var formData = new FormData();
        axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
        axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
        axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
        axios.get(`/api/drawings/`)
            
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            setDrawingItems(response.data);
          
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    },[]);
    
    
    return (
    <div>
    <div>
        <p>FileList</p>
        {drawingItems.length != 0 &
           
            <EnhancedTable data={drawingItems}></EnhancedTable>
        }
    </div>
    </div>

    );
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: `&&` you missed one `&` when conditionally rendering `EnhancedTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try with this please:

```
<div>
        <p>FileList</p>
        {drawingItems &&
            <EnhancedTable data={drawingItems}></EnhancedTable>
        }
    </div>
```

btw you can improve useEffect part

```
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData= async()=>{
          const response = await axios.get(`/api/drawings/`)
          if(response){
            setDrawingItems(response?.data);
          }
        }
       fetchData() 
    },[]);
```

Comment: You are missing `await` when assigning to `response`, which then causes `drawingItems` to become `undefined`

Comment: I changed & -> && it works!! It's quite careless mistake....

Comment: Your `setDrawingItems(response?.data)` will crash if request fail. Because setting `undefined` to set will make it crash at `.length`